# Installing RubberDuck but the Explorer graphic goes round and round

Tags: excel, rubberduck

followed directions and got it installed. see code in standard module

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'@TestModule
'@Folder("Tests")

Private Assert As Object
Private Fakes As Object

'@ModuleInitialize
Private Sub ModuleInitialize()
   'this method runs once per module.
   Set Assert = CreateObject("Rubberduck.AssertClass")
   Set Fakes = CreateObject("Rubberduck.FakesProvider")
   Debug.Print "ModuleInitialize"
End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Private Sub ModuleCleanup()
   'this method runs once per module.
   Set Assert = Nothing
   Set Fakes = Nothing
   Debug.Print "ModuleCleanup"
End Sub

'@TestInitialize
Private Sub TestInitialize()
   'This method runs before every test in the module.
   .Debug.Print "TestInitialize"
End Sub

'@TestCleanup
Private Sub TestCleanup()
   'this method runs after every test in the module.
   Debug.Print "TestCleanup"
End Sub
```

problem if i run the Explorer, it just goes round and round

what am i doing wrong

Comment: This is not a good place to ask for support with 3rd party extensions. You can find the developers and talk to them here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking

Comment: Or you can check for a matching issue in their github: https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues

Comment: Unit tests are discovered during parsing, but this module has no test methods in it (that would be a `Sub` procedure with a `'@TestMethod` annotation, somewhere in that test module. Are you referring to the *Code Explorer* or the *Test Explorer* toolwindow? What does the "refresh" commandbar button say?

Comment: So i did the basic install. added a TestModule. i see where i needed to add a sub so i added it. then i went to rubberduck menu and picked Test Explorer. never finishs parsing. what do i need to do?

Comment: I was having similar issues with the Code Explorer, tests not working and no intellisence. Closing Excel and restarting sorted all of this out. Simple fix but annoying issue.